# how to edit an array element present in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of strings present in firestore. I want to edit the string present at a particular index. How can I do this?

For example, let the array be ["help","me","please"];

How can I change "help" to "don't help" in flutter?

The closest I've gotten to editing the array is adding an element, which I do by FieldValue.arrayunion().

Is it possible to edit an element present at a particular index? Or am I gonna have to fetch the entire array, update it locally, and then upload the entire array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with a single update.  You have to do exactly as you said: read the document, make changes to the array in memory, write the new array back to the document.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to edit an element present at a particular index?

This is not possible.

> Or am I gonna have to fetch the entire array, update it locally, and then upload the entire array?

That's indeed one option. The other option is to [use an `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), which work if the items in the array are unique.

Also see:

- [Flutter: Update specific index in list (Firestore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123464/flutter-update-specific-index-in-list-firestore/59123491#59123491)
- [Flutter: How to update an Array within an Array in the firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212886/flutter-how-to-update-an-array-within-an-array-in-the-firestore/61213925#61213925)